# ML or rule based

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I already have 85 accuracy on my sklearn text classifier. What are the advantages and disadvantages of making a rule based system? Can save doing double the work? Maybe you can provide me with sources and evidence for each side, so that I can make the decision baed on my cirucumstances. Again, I want to know when ruls-based approach is favorable versus when a ML based approach is favorable? Thanks!

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: @molbdnilo what, did i goof and put a wrong tag? oh, i am sorry. thank you for writing your comment. it is nice that someone with experience like you takes time to help a beginnger like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

Instead of going one way or another, you can set up a hybrid model. Look at typical errors your machine learning classifier makes, and see if you can come up with a set of rules that capture those errors. Then run these rules on your input, and if they applied, finish there; if not, pass the input on to the classifier.

In the past I did this with a probabilistic part-of-speech tagger. It's difficult to tune a probabilistic model, but it's easy to add a few pre- or post-processing rules to capture some consistent errors.

Comment: let us see if i get what you mean by 
"Then run these rules on your input, and if they applied, finish there; if not, pass the input on to the classifier."
you mean first run the rules on the input, and then only proceed to the machine learning if...what?

Comment: @yishairasowsky If the rules don't apply. For my POS Tagger I was matching certain word combinations (pre) or tag-sequences (post) that usually were erroneous. If you use patterns to trigger rules, then if no rule triggers you can use your classifier.

Comment: I would think it good practice to explain _why_ an answer is downvoted, rather than just doing it without giving any idea what one thinks is wrong with it.

Comment: I agree about only down voting if you exaplin why. But I don't see that anyone downvoted your answer...

Comment: @yishairasowsky It has one up and one down vote...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215311/discussion-between-yishairasowsky-and-oliver-mason).

Comment: gr8 advice from @Oliver Mason

Answer (score 0):

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6674229787218776064?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6674229787218776064%2C6674239716663156736%29

Yoel Krupnik (CTO & co-founder | smrt - AI For Accounting) writes:

> *I think it really depends on the specific problem.  Some problems can be completely solved with rule based logic,  some require machine learning (often in combination with rule based logic before or after). 
>   Advantages of the rule based are that it doesn't require labeled training data, might quickly provide decent results used as a benchmark and helps you better understand the problem for future labeling / text manipulations required by the ML algorithm.*